# How to use iLike operator with Sequelize to make case insensitive queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, case-insensitive

I am using Sequelize along with PostgreSQL in managing my database.
I would like to perform a case insensitive search query. When I googled it up, some people said that I can use "iLike" operator to do so. I tried to implement this way:

```
var getRadiosByGenre = function(Radio,Genre,genreName){
    Genre.findOne({where:{name: { $iLike: genreName}}})}
```

where genreName is a string.
But, I keep getting this error:

> Error: Invalid value { '$iLike': 'art' }

Does anyone know the correct way of using iLike with sequelize?
Thanks mates(s). :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should use `Sequelize.Op` :

```
var getRadiosByGenre = function(Radio,Genre,genreName) {
  Genre.findOne({
    where: {
      name: {
        [Sequelize.Op.iLike]: genreName
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Don't forget to add `%` before or after your `genreName` if you want to make a partial query.

See the docs [here >](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)

Comment: Thank you, for the reference but this is how to implement it exactly: var getRadiosByGenre = function(Radio,Genre,genreName){
    Genre.findOne({where :{name:{[ Op.iLike ]:'%'+genreName}}})

Comment: Yes as I stated you should add the % sign if needed ! glad I could help